# How to write average function based on values from other 2 columns

Tags: excel

I have some problem about writing a function in MS-Excel.
I have data like:

```
columnA       columnB     columnC
0              -4           5
0              -4           15
0              -2           7
1              -5           8
1              -5           6
2               8           4
```

I would like to get average data in column D from column C that is based on the values of column A and B like:

```
columnD
10                 // comment ---> from A=0,B=-4 (15+5)
7                  // comment ---> from A=0,B=-2 (7)
7                  // comment ---> from A=1,B=-5 (8+6)
4                  // comment ---> from A=2,B=8 (4)
```

I try to write but I don't know how to set relation between column A and B.
Please show me how to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to group rows by columns A and B then calculate the average of columnC for each group? If so, this can be done with a pivot table.

Comment: are you adding the next two rows of column C?

Comment: I try to get average of column C by grouping with column A and B write into column D.

You can see '0' from column A and '-4' from column B, they have 2 line and they contain '5' and '15' in column C.

So, I would like to average them and write into column D --> (5+15/line of grouping) = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using Excel 2007 and up you can try using `Averageifs`:

If you have data like below:
[image]

Enter this formula in `D2`:

`=IF(SUM(A1:B1)=SUM(A2:B2),"",AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$7,A$2:A$7,A2,B$2:B$7,B2))`

The result will be as shown.

**Edit1:**
Now to really get to your desired output, you'll need another formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D$7,SMALL(IF(D$2:D$7<>"",ROW(D$2:D$7)),ROW(A1))),"")`

This is entered in `E2` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The result would be:

[image]

**Edit2:**
 To answer follow up in comment
To count, you use `Countifs` function instead like this:

`=IF(SUM($A1:$B1)=SUM($A2:$B2),"",COUNTIFS(A$2:A$7,A2,B$2:B$7,B2))`

It will give you below result when entered in `F2`.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It really help.
But the way, is it possible to return value in unique row, for example a=0 and b=-4 have 2 rows, so I want it only 1 row.

Comment: So, please help me a little more.
How to write function to count unique number of column A and B.
Example, A=0 B=-4 --> count =2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my edit. Also you might want to [Check This Out](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index.php) to know more about Excel Functions.